# Cannot access CI Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little problem with a tiny CodeIgniter app developed by another guy who had my job a while back. The app is already implemented, I just have to modify it a bit. The problem is that I can only access the two controllers that are already created. If I create another controller and I try to access it I get a 404 error.

Controller name: `Test.php`

Code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    die('test');
}
}?>
```

Result when trying to access it by `myapp.com/test` or `myapp.com/index.php/test` or `myapp.com/index.php/test/index`:

`404 Page Not Found. The page you requested was not found.`

Config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['brand'] = '/';
$route['brand/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'brands/brand/$1/$2';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Pages.php and Brands.php are the two controllers already implemented.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I try to access via url one of the other two controllers it works just fine. But I need to create new controllers for the changes I have to implement. What should I do? Where should I look for problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the config/routes.php as well.

Comment: Check routes.php in config folder. Oh, @nightgaunt was faster.

Comment: I edited my question to add the content of routes.php.

Comment: Try with index.php in url like `myapp.com/index.php/test` if that works then you need a htaccess file in main directory. You also not need `?>` at end of file as explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Comment: Already tried that. Also tried `myapp.com/index.php/test/index`. Same result. I tried to remove the closing tag and nothing...

Comment: try with out die('test') use `echo  'test';` and remove `?>` at end of page

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I replaced `die('test');` with `echo 'test';` and that didn't change anything... I removed the closing tag, too.

Comment: @AlinN : can you comment this line and try?? ```$route['brand'] = '/';```

Comment: @kishor10d that didn't work, either.

Comment: Please check that any hooks implemented, and please update htaccess in question if you have.

Comment: Did you try adding a route to that controller ? ```$route['test'] = 'test/index';```
That might not reveal why the problem occured but may solve the problem.

Comment: @kishor10d hooks file is empty and I edited the question to include .htaccess content.

Comment: @SEJBR yes, I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: All is perfect i think, change controller file name 'test.php' and try again.

Comment: @HiteshSolanki didn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm that the controller name is `Test.php` with an upper case `T` at the beginning?  Also, what file permissions are set on the controller?  It could be that apache doesn't have access to the file to be able to use it.

Comment: Maybe a core override? Check 'core' directory.
Actually Hitesh Solanki may be onto something. Linux is case sensitive so you should take a note on that. Autoloading libraries also breaks if you name files with upper and load them with nonupper characters.

Comment: @gabe3886 yes, it is upper case T. I tried with lower case, too, with no result. Permissions on all the controllers are the same: 0644.

Comment: @SEJBR are you talking about `application/core` or `system/core`? And what should I check?

Comment: application/core If the previous developer touched system/core you may be in trouble. Well there may be a something with "routes" in name and so on. You can break a lot of stuff if you don't know what you're doing with CI Overrides.

Comment: @AlinN are the file and group owners set correctly, the same as the other controllers?

Comment: Please mention ```RewriteBase /```

Comment: @SEJBR `application/core` only has its default `index.html` file.
@gabe3886 yes, they are the same.
@kishor10d I added `RewriteBase /` to `.htaccess`, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Out of curiosity... If you change content on one of the working pages, does it show on the website? In some cases cache systems also cache php files and so, no changes would show without apache/nginx restart.

Comment: @SEJBR I tried it now and you're right. I changed one of the working pages and it does not show on the website. So what should I do? I mean I will make many changes to the app. That means a restart would be necessary after every change on the live server?

Comment: I've had that problem where I work on someones dev system, sadly that wasn't part of my job so someone from support team fixed it. Best shot would be googling questions about "php files getting cached", "php changes not showing up" and finding a solution on your own since there may be multiple reasons that occurs and only you can test them. Answer your question if you find what you are looking for. I believe that might help someone in the future.

Comment: This looks like it may be a decent solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/267405/how-to-prevent-caching-of-php-files

Comment: @SEJBR an email has been sent to the hosting company to let them know about the problem and to check the `apc.stat` value (as said in the article provided by you). As soon as I get an answer, I will let you know. Thank you very much for your help in determining the cause of the problem!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151890/discussion-on-question-by-alin-n-cannot-access-ci-controller).